# How to prevent adding even/odd class in the nested table

Tags: jquery

```
 $(function(){

                $("tr:even").addClass("even");
                $("tr:odd").addClass("odd");


            }) 


     <table>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>A-1</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>A-2</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Running the above code, the even/odd class has been added to the nested table, like:

```
<table>
    <tr class="even">
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr class="even"><td>A-1</td></tr>
                <tr class="odd"><td>A-2</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What change should I do to make even/odd class are not in the nested table, the output as below:

```
<table>
    <tr class="even">
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr><td>A-1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>A-2</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an `id` to your outer table, then use the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$("#yourTable > tbody > tr:even").addClass("even");
$("#yourTable > tbody > tr:odd").addClass("odd");
```

The child selector selects only direct children, rather than all descendants (your current selector simply selects all `td` elements in the DOM, regardless of which table they are in).

Comment: Bear in mind that many, if not all, browsers add a `tbody` element to `tables` to contain the `tr` elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the HTML you could add classes to the rows you want to exclude, then specify that class in a 'not' selctor in your jQuery selectors -

**jQuery**

```
$("tr:not(.inner):even").addClass("even");
$("tr:not(.inner):odd").addClass("odd");
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="inner">
            <td>
                <table >
                    <tr class="inner"><td>A-1</td></tr>
                    <tr class="inner"><td>A-2</td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This will apply no styles to the 'tr' conatining the nested table, so odd style will be applied to 'A', even style will be applied to 'B'.

Working Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/yPbfq/